# SELECTing all ActiveRecord instances where date difference is smaller than X hours

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Rails 4 `ActiveRecord` model with two `DateTime` fields: `dt1` and `dt2`.

How do I retrieve all instances of this model for which `dt2` is less than X (say, 18) hours after `dt1`?

Comment: `Model.where('dt2 < ?', dt1 - x.hours)` ?

Comment: @kiddorails: the problem is that `dt1` can be different for each row. It's not a fixed value that applies to each row. I.E. for each row, we need to detect the time difference between its *own* value of `dt1` versus it's *own* value of `dt2`.

Comment: Understood your point :) I managed to do it with AREL but seems like Mathias suggested a better approach already below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Model.where(%q{ dt2 - dt1 < interval '18 hours' })
```

`18 hours` can be a variable you assign dynamically through a param.

```
dt_diff = '22 days' # or 18 hours or 3 years
Model.where(%q{ "dt2 - dt1 < interval '#{dt_diff}'" })
```

Comment: Just a small correction: to actually inject `dt_diff` into the query, you'd have to do: `Mode.where("dt2 - dt1 < interval '#{dt_diff}'")`

Comment: Right, forgot the string interpolation. Sorry ;) I'll add it.